# Relation between the number of block and transaction rate in Quorum

Tags: quorum, consensus

I want to know the relation between the number of blocks generated and the transaction send rate in quorum.
I did some experiments on quorum with RAFT consensus, and I get (I invoked the same function of a deployed smart contract in each workload)

> 10 blocks for 10 transaction send rate
>
> 7 blocks for 20 transaction send rate
>
> 21 blocks for 30 transaction send rate
>
> 21 blocks for 50 transaction send rate
>
> 20 blocks for 100 transaction send rate
>
> 23 blocks for 200 transaction send rate
>
> 156 blocks for 1000 transaction send rate

I can't determine the logic for blocks generation with relation to the transaction send rate

Answer (score 1):

By default, Quorum in Raft mode attempts to create blocks every 50ms but only if a pending txn exists. It is rate limited (and is controlled by a cli parameter), so if 2 txns made it into the queue between the block minting, then both of these txns will get minted in the next block; by extension, if you were able to send 1000 txns between the mint time, they would all go into the next block.

This is a very well documented topic with full detail here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/raft/doc.md